# Yii: Render Json Of A Model In Controller Action

Tags: jquery, yii

well I am new to Yii and have a problem: I am sending a ajax POST request (with firstname and lastname parameters) from a Jquery Mobile app to the Yii WorkerController's actionJSON() function. This function (action) retrieves the worker model with column values of submitted firstname and lastname POST values. So here is the code - The problem in the end is that neither of my onSuccess nor onError methods are called in jquery.

JQuery Mobile -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){

            var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "localhost/myYiiVodovod1/index.php?r=site/json",
                //crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
        //dataType   : 'json',
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Yii workerController - I am not sure whether the findByAttribute() is correct :

```
public function actionJson(){

          if((isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName']))){

            header('Content-type: application/json');  

            $model=$this->loadModelTwo($_POST['firstName'],$_POST['lastName']);

            echo CJSON::encode($model);  

        }
            Yii::app()->end();  

    }

public function loadModelTwo($fname,$lname){

        $model = Worker::model()->findByAttributes(array('first_name' => $fname, 'last_name' => $lname));

        if($model===null){
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        }              

        return $model;

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is simple unless you have a typo. You say your `actionJson` is located in `workerContoller` however your ajax call is to `localhost/myYiiVodovod1/index.php?r=site/json` therefore unless you some special URL mapping it should be hitting the `siteController`. Most likely you just need correct your url on your ajax call.

Also when dealing with ajax calls it is always nice to have Firebug installed or some other plugin so you can see the ajax call and the response.